# PHP menu with AJAX external content, no refresh

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, external

As a brief description, what im trying to achieve is a menu thats built with PHP, but content is loaded via AJAX requests, without page refresh.

So far im using PHP to build an unordered list menu:

```
<?php
        $folder = 'includes/';
        $filetype = '*.*';
        $files = glob($folder.$filetype);
        for ($i=0; $i<count($files); $i++) {
            echo '<li>';
            echo '<a name="'.$i.'" title="'.substr($files[$i],strlen($folder),strpos($files[$i],            '.')-strlen($folder)).'" alt="'.$i.'" href="'.$files[$i].'">'.substr($files[$i],strlen($folder),strpos($files[$i], '.') -strlen($folder)).'</a>';
        echo '</li>';}
                ?>
```

... and then trying to incorporate the jQuery request within the PHP itself. The problem is, using something like [this](http://tutorialzine.com/2009/09/simple-ajax-website-jquery/) ajax tutorial, is that i cant use apostrophes within the PHP or it breaks. Most other examples are the same or need to be exclusively written individually.

eg.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.ajaxtrigger').click(function(){
    $('#target').load('ajaxcontent.html');
  });
});
```

Something like that would be ideal as i could call the the ID within the PHP but then defeats the purpose of reading the directory.

The end result being that when i upload a new file to the 'includes' directory, the PHP writes me a new link to the menu and AJAX will call it automatically.

Is it possible? Thanks for your time.

Comment: Sounds like you have some logic conflicts to work out in your head before putting it into practical code.

Comment: Most definitely, im just lost.

Comment: I’d suggest ending the `<?php ?>` block and dropping back to normal HTML, then call an external .js file with a script tag. Will that work?

Comment: Do you mean getting rid of the PHP and going back to HTML or building onto the end of it with HTML. The latter may work if i could incorporate an ID into the anchor tag.